# MVC: Class isn't being called from an html tag

Tags: html, css, asp.net-mvc, razor

I am linking my css to my razor form:

```
<link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/CreateAccount.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

Then, I am trying to call the class called `create-fieldset` from the css in the fieldset tag:

```
<fieldset class="create-fieldset">
```

it doesn't work but calling the `create-field class` and the `firstname-field id` from a field does:

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Firstname, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "create-field", id = "firstname-field" }})
```

`body` and `*` are working on the form, but `create-fieldset` isn't (it only works when I adjust it and save the css file, but when I refresh the page, `create-field` doesn't work).

Here is my css:

```
*{
    box-sizing:border-box;
}

body{
    margin:0px;
}

.create-fieldset{
    margin:0px;
    width:200px;
}

.create-field{
    font-family:Arial;
}

#firstname-field{
    width:200px;
}
```

Why isn't it working for the fieldset?

**EDIT:** It works on Firefox but not Google Chrome

Comment: Not sure what you mean by it doesn't work. It worked here in Chrome as well.

Comment: @derloopkat It worked for me, too. I think I have to build or rebuild the solution.